# Extract first four digits from string within an list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of folder names. Some names contain numbers only and others have the numbers prefixed before some text.

Where the folder name contains both numbers and text, i would like to extract only the numbers (first four digits).

```
internal_list = [f.name for f in os.scandir(internal_path) if f.is_dir() ]
print(internal_list)
```

`internal_list` shows a list as follows

```
[1001 Support, 1021 Training, 1022, 1023, 1033 Procedures]
```

I would like internal_digits to show:

```
[1001, 1021, 1022, 1023, 1033]
```

---

```
internal_digits = []
for filename in internal_list:
    if filename in '0123456789':
        internal_digits.append(filename[0:4])
print (internal_digits)
```

Comment: if the name is 12 Support the 4 digits will be only 12 or what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
internal_digits=[i.split()[0] for i in internal_list]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expression matching:

```
In [9]: [int(re.match(r'\d+', name).group(0)) for name in internal_list]
Out[9]: [1001, 1021, 1022, 1023, 1033]
```

Notes:

- This assumes there's always a match.  In production code I'd probably write this as a `for` loop with error checking.
- This takes all the digits at the start of the string.  Changing `\d+` to `\d{4}` would take exactly four digits if that's what you require.